# Can't read file data twice using QAxObject

Tags: c++, excel, qt, qaxobject

I read excel file using `QAxBase` and `QAxObject`.

I got global variable `QAxObject* db_workbook;` where I store pointer to some workbook(don't know why it called like that, but whatever) in excel. I need it because of throught it I need to get excel file data in few functions, not just only one.

When `readExcelFile` method executes fine, in `test_function()` an exception

[image]

appears at this line `sheet_N = db_workbook->querySubObject("Worksheets(int)", 1);`

Why does it happens and how to fix it?

Code part is here

```
//
QAxObject* db_workbook;

//for read what we need to
void importdb_module::readExcelFile(QAxObject* excel, QString& file_path){

    if(initExcel(excel)){

        QAxObject* workbooks = excel->querySubObject("WorkBooks");
        workbooks->dynamicCall("Open (const QString&)", file_path);
        QAxObject* workbook = excel->querySubObject("ActiveWorkBook");
        db_workbook = workbook;//global ptr points same adress now
        QAxObject* worksheets = workbook->querySubObject("WorkSheets");

        //test getting sheet num 1 name
        QAxObject* sheet_hh = workbook->querySubObject("Worksheets(int)", 1);

        QString sheet_name = sheet_hh->property("Name").toString();

        qDebug()<<sheet_name<<"TEST!";//here everything works fine
    }
}

void importdb_module::test_function(){
    QAxObject* sheet_N;
    //ERROR IS HERE!
    sheet_N = db_workbook->querySubObject("Worksheets(int)", 1);

    QString sheet_name = sheet_N->property("Name").toString();

    qDebug()<<sheet_name;
}


//executes on button click
void importdb_module::testExlOp(QString &_path){
    QAxObject* excel;
    QStringList spreadsheet_list; //get spreadsheet list when opening file
    QString path = _path;//gonna use GUI choose

    if(initExcel(excel)){
        if (readExcelFile(excel, path)){
            //
            test_function();
            excel->dynamicCall("Quit(void)");
            }else{
            //error output
            QMessageBox::information(0, "", "Error");
        }
    }


    delete excel;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you repeat the `QAxObject* sheet_hh = workbook->querySubObject("Worksheets(int)", 1);` query with a second variable immediately after?  What happens if this line appears before the line `QAxObject* worksheets = workbook->querySubObject("WorkSheets");`?

Comment: `db_workbook` is probably NULL, try checking it.

Comment: This just looks like a giant memory leak.  Surely there's a delete call *somewhere*?  Which kills that global variable.

Comment: @dauphic not, I checked it before, look
http://i.imgur.com/L8X3wbH.png
http://i.imgur.com/jIvYrZ1.png

Comment: @abiessu sorry i cant check it right now, deep night here, got no VS and Qt in my laptop (I made post text and screenshots few hours before posting it)

Comment: @DanilGholtsman: Yes, your `db_workbook` is pointing to garbage. It's not a valid object; you can tell by looking at `__vfptr` and noticing that it isn't pointing to valid memory.

Comment: @dauphic but how? isn't there same adresses?

Comment: Possibly you deleted it somewhere or have heap corruption.

Comment: @dauphic hmm, I'm pretty sure that I didn't delete any related stuff.

Comment: @dauphic: we have enough code I think, there is no place for a delete between the lines `if (readExcelFile(excel, path)){` and `test_function();` in the main function except possibly for the `qDebug()` bit.

Comment: Any chance the `test_function` is called somewhere else?

Comment: @abiessu no, it's not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have a dangling pointer. Use `QPointer<QAxObject>` instead of a naked pointer. It will reset itself to null when the instance of `QAxObject` gets destructed.

Generally speaking, in this day and age, you're not supposed to be using naked pointers for anything that's not implicitly owned by something else. This means that for `QObjects` that have parents you don't need to do use smart pointers (although it doesn't hurt any). Generally speaking, smart pointers don't hurt. Use them.

Comment: Oh, never heard about such things before. I changed global var declaration `QPointer<QAxObject> database_workbook;` but I got still same error.
Well, do I need to use `QPointer<QAxObject>` instaed of every `QAxObject` pointer?

Comment: Well, I fixed it, your answer really helped. Such stuff is so complicated and I am so stupid :\